# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent'

Tags: python, selenium, module, user-agent

I successfully downloaded fake_useragent module (and double checked it), but I still make my code running, I get the same mistake "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent'"

My code:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.random)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\syrbu\PycharmProjects\python selenium\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent'
```

Comment: What was your steps of installing the package? What was the output?

Comment: Make sure you're running through the virtual environment that you had installed it to